# openssl does not load engine from config file

Tags: configuration, openssl

I'm using openssl-1.0.1f. And I'm trying to load the pkcs11 engine in the config file, but it doesn't work. Here is my config:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def

[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section

[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = /usr/lib/ssl/engines/engine_pkcs11.so
MODULE_PATH = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/opensc-pkcs11.so
default_algorithms = ALL
init = 0
```

Here are the results from `openssl engine pkcs11 -t`:

```
1996159072:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpkcs11.so): /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
1996159072:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
1996159072:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:447:
1996159072:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:418:id=pkcs11
```

Comment: What is your distribution/OS? Is the library opensc installed? Apparently, the engine needs "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpkcs11.so".

Comment: OS: raspbian jessie lite. opensc was installed because I successfully used pykcs11 lib to generate private/public key to smart card.

Comment: Ok. And what is the output of `locate libpkcs11.so` (or `find /usr/lib -name libpkcs11.so` if locate is not available)?

Comment: Output is nothing, so what are libs I have to install?

Comment: It seems that your problem is a version incompatibility. In sid the correct path is `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpkcs11.so` but in Jessie the path is `/usr/lib/ssl/engines/engine_pkcs11.so` as in your conf. The package is libengine-pkcs11-openssl. Did you install openssl from the debian repository?

Comment: Openssl is default in raspbian jessie. Should I reinstall openssl from repository or source code?

Comment: Perhaps, you should use the SO_PATH option in the configuration to give the explicit path to the pkcs11 library and see if it works. https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Quick-Start-with-OpenSC#testing-using-openssl

Comment: I did, but openssl still throughts error.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, you are not loading the config file, to load an OpenSSL config file, you must specify the path through an environment variable : 
`export OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/config`
 Then you can run 
 `openssl engine pkcs11 -t -c`
 At least, the correct engine and module will be loaded. If you still have errors, you need to make a new post.